# _stricoll is unsolved while linking the libmingwex.a with vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, linker, ffmpeg, cmake, mingw

I am tending to build some app which staticly links the ffmpeg libs on windows 8. I have successfully build the static lib of ffmpeg in mingw/msys env on windows 8. Then I use cmake to generate the vs2010 project to start work with my app.

While I am trying to build the first dead simple main program, I got quite some link errors.

```
extern "C" {

// to work around error:
// 'UINT64_C': identifier not found
#ifndef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#endif


#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    av_register_all();
    return 0;
}
```

After struggling with a bunch of unresolved symbols, I come up with the following libraries to link with in order:

```
c:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/libiconv.a
libavcodec.a
libavdevice.a
libavfilter.a
libavformat.a
libavutil.a
libswresample.a
libswscale.a
c:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/libgcc.a
c:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/libws2_32.a
c:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a
c:/MinGW/mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a
```

Finally there is one unresolved symbol issue not able to fix:

```
libmingwex.a(glob.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
                       _stricoll referenced in function _glob_match
```

I tried to add some a fake function, but still not help :(

```
int  __cdecl _stricoll(_In_z_  const char * _Str1, _In_z_  const char * _Str2)
{
    return 0;
};
```

I googled it the whole morning, but nobody ever mentioned this problem. I guess there should be simple reason and solution for this, maybe because of my ignorance on simple knowledge.

Comment: Have you tried it with `libmoldname100.a` and `libmsvcr100.a`

Comment: @moskito-x Yes! it is the libmoldname100.a. Thank you very much!.

Comment: while I am using mingw-w64 to go through the compiling steps, I got a new link error: __libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-pesect.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol__ ______image_base______ __referenced in function__ ____FindPESectionByName.__     Do I really need to modify and recompile the libmingw32 to get rid of it? It's driving me nuts.

Comment: you can not mix mingw32 with mingw64 . use mingw32.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by moskito-x and OP.*

In MinGW libs, the symbol _stricoll is defined in libmoldname100.a.